# How to I "lock" my choice of DNS settings?

Tags: server, dns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have changed my DNS setting on my router to one of the [cleanbrowsing DNS](https://cleanbrowsing.org/) filters. This setting can be changed easily from the router webpage. Even if I set a strong password for the router, it still has a manual reset button that can be used. I am new to ubuntu and I wanted to see if setting this on the device works better. I know how to change this setting at the level of my device by going into the wifi settings panel but this is even more easy to change back. I would like to know if there is a better way to lock this DNS setting in place on my device.

I do understand that the root user can do pretty much anything so there may not be a full proof way but I just want to make it as hard as possible for a casual user to change this setting.

Thanks!

Comment: What you do in the router is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: You (or your kids) can set DNS in browsers like Firefox too even if you set it in the router and Ubuntu network manager.

Comment: I do not understand why are you letting any "casual user" press the reset button on *anything* in your home. If you and others in your home are having some disagreement about use of your network, that seems like a negotiation or mediation issue more than a technical support question. I can think of several ways around most parental controls on most platforms, and I'm an old duffer who doesn't even need to try.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Yes it isn't. I mentioned that for context.

Comment: @user68186: I am aware of that and I am using a separate filter on my browser for this. I want this setting to apply for any browser.

Comment: @user535733: casual users refer to my family. I'm aware that there are ways around these controls but like I said, i want to make it hard at least.

Comment: Ubuntu's not a great choice for that kind of lockdown unless you really know what you are doing. It's designed for rather the opposite -- to be robust and flexible and resilient and user-configurable.